# deleting skype webcam background with python

Tags: python, opencv

i made a live webcam background remover with opencv-python.
am searching for a way to make it to work with other apps like zoom , skype and others so every live webcam app remove its background with my app

s.th like XplitVcam that remove background from skype, zoom and .

my code itself work perfectly in a opencv window but i want it for skype and zoom.

i want s,th like this app : https://www.xsplit.com/vcam

any body can help ?
thanks.

i searched in internet but found nothing.

best regards - amin

Comment: To do that you would need some method to remove the background such as AI processing, then blur the image, then put the foreground only image over the blurred image.

Comment: i removed background with opencv , i want to know how to set it to skype and zoom

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "set it to skype and zoom"? I do not know how to interface OpenCV with skype or zoom. Is that your question?

Comment: yes i want my opencv window that i removed background using it show in skype instead of defualt webcam

Comment: As I said, I do not know how to interface OpenCV with skype or zoom

Comment: You need some virtual video software, which is able to get the video from the real camera, process it and then make the processed video available to applications by means of a virtual camera device driver. Maybe, this can work like that: https://opensource.com/article/20/8/obs-virtual-webcam